# In Two way SSL it is necessary that both certificates(client/server) built using same tool

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool, two-way

I need a clarity for two-way SSL, if I Create Client self-sign certificate, using OpenSSL then save it in Pkcs12 file and Server self-sign certificate using Java keytool then save it in Jks file. Can both certificate work for two-way SSL? 
Which TLS version openssl used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of a certificate is a standard and independent of a specific tool. This means it does not matter what tool is used to create certificates as long as it creates proper certificates. Also, the TLS protocol version used inside a connection has nothing to do with the certificate used for the connection and what tool was used to create the certificate.

Comment: it means the certificate stored in pkcs12 file and jks file are both in same format? no difference in formatting, storing?

Comment: No, it means the actual certificates once retrieved are in the same format. PKCS#12 and JKS are different formats for certificate *containers.*

Comment: @MuhammadHassan: A certificate itself is a binary structure but it can be stored in various encodings or containers, i.e. PEM, JKS, PKCS#12.... But these are all different representations of the same thing. On the wire during the TLS handshake there is a single format and TLS stacks know how to retrieve the certificate from the various encodings and containers and use it within the TLS handshake.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for details.